# define multiple objects in a drop down list into separate variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

Hi i am trying to get these objects in javascript defined as separate variables but i am unsuccessful, how would you be able to get these values seprate so for example, the login= "uk" and another variable for review="com"

```
            <label for="location">Country</label>
            <select name="location" id="location" value="" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value='{"login":"uk","review":"com"}'>UK</option>
                <option value='{"login":"Canada","review":"ca"}'> Canada</option>

            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery you can do the following:

```
var login, review;

$("#location").on("change", function(){
    var obj = JSON.parse($(this).val());
    login = obj.login;
    review = obj.review;
});
```

```js
var login, review;

$("#location").on("change", function(){
    var obj = JSON.parse($(this).val());
    login = obj.login;
    review = obj.review;
  
    console.log(review);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="location">Country</label>

<select name="location" id="location" value="" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value='{"login":"uk","review":"com"}'>UK</option>
    <option value='{"login":"Canada","review":"ca"}'> Canada</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great, is there a way i can store them both in a cookie after?

Comment: @joe You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).